# Calculating habitat openness from digital elevation models (DEM)?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, grass-gis, habitat-modeling

I have digital elevation models (DEM) of an area and want to calculate habitat openness.

Can anyone help calculating habitat openness from a digital elevation models (DEM)?

I tried the Package 'horizon' - cran.r (R: The R Project for Statistical Computing), but got some strange results. I'm not familiar with this type of analysis, hence I do not know the scale. I'm about to analyse habitat selection in a owl inhabiting coastal and maritime heath habitats. I have GPS-positions and want to check if the owl are more likely to stay at elevations in the terrain (place with a good overview of the landscape). The owl has a home-range of about 30 to 50 km2, the accuracy of each owl GPS position is about +/- 25 m

The two DEM files could be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ct02cns54c9i1wo/AAAaAT-h-F8L-FA8npm6flFoa?dl=0

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a particular measure of openness in mind? What scale of openness is required for the habitat you’re modelling?

Comment: I tried the Package 'horizon' - cran.r (R: The R Project for Statistical Computing), but got some strange results. I'm not familiar with this type of analysis, hence I do not know the scale.  I'm about to analyse habitat selection in a owl inhabiting coastal and maritime heath habitats. I have GPS-positions and want to check if the owl are more likely to stay at elevations in the terrain (place with a good overview of the landscape). The owl has a home-range of about  30 to 50 km2, the accuracy of each owl GPS position is about +/- 25 m.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 2):

There is r.skyview addon:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/r.skyview.html. It's a visualization technique, but it computes terrain openness. See the referenced paper at the bottom of the manual page for details. I don't know how to use it with your specific requirements, but it's a start.